# How to turn off textview whitespace trimming?

Tags: android, textview

I want to display a string with leading whitespace in a Textview. But what I can see is that the android Textview is trimming all leading/trailing whitespace. Is there a way to turn this behavior off?

Comment: I think this should be very useful to you 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/android-remove-useless-whitespace-from-styled-string

Comment: That's unfortunately right. I just verified with some other view and there it works as expected. Sorry...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Old question but if you are not satisfied with "It Does Not trim itself." answer from comments this might help you.

If you are using resource strings with leading or trailing spaces, this is your issue: [How to keep the spaces at the end and/or at the beginning of a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587056/android-string-concatenate-how-to-keep-the-spaces-at-the-end-and-or-beginnin)

TextView indeed doesn't trim whitespaces but whatever reads strings from XML does. Use `\u0020` instead of spaces.