# Android textview whitespaces are disappearing

Tags: java, android, textview, whitespace

For a game I'm using TextView which has a background and right aligned text. Well I don't want the text to show up in the absolute right but a bit away from the border. So I've tried to add a whitespace in the end of text (   `tvTextView.setText(textToBeAdded + ' ');`  )

The problem is that when I use **whitespace as first or last character they are being trimmed automatically.** I don't want to use dummy view as back ground and TextView over it, because I think those things are going to decrease performance on old devices. Thank you for any suggestion.

---

Using **tvTextView.setPadding(0, 0, GLRenderer.dpW[5], 0);** solved the problem.
Still I would like to be able to use space in the end and at the begining of text...

Comment: You can try to use `&#160;`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2206684/2198638.

Comment: Well I've tryed margin it was moving background as well but padding solved the problem thank you.