# Why Colon before space is consider as Space but after Colon it is not Consider in Android

Tags: android, string, android-layout

I have Simple Question regarding space define in `string` in `string.xml` file.

Let's say If we define string

```
<string name="regNumber">RegNumber : </string>
```

it will consider space before `Colon` not after. if we have put space after `Colon` then we have to define below way.

```
<string name="regNumber">RegNumber :\u0020</string>
```

or let's say this way also

```
<string name="regNumber">RegNumber :&#160;</string>
```

**Question :** why space is not Consider After `Colon` without writing any code ?

**Brief Explanation :**

If write this

```
<string name="regNumber">RegNumber : </string>
```

it will put space before `Colon` but not After the `Colon`

so the text will be `RegNumber :`

But My Question it will output like this it will not consider before `Colon` why it is consider.

`RegNumber:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the spaces at the end and/or at the beginning of a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587056/how-to-keep-the-spaces-at-the-end-and-or-at-the-beginning-of-a-string)

Comment: *My question why is not consider as Space I want to set Space.* - because otherwise, it gets discarded.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know when we write `&#160;` or `\u0020` it will add space but my question is why it is not consider `space` after `Colon` because before `Colon` it is consider. Now remove `flag` if you have clear Idea.

Comment: The colon is not a whitespace and a whitespace before it is not a leading/trailing whitespace. All leading/trailing whitespace is removed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are not `clear` with my question. I am not say how to set , I am say that why is not consider after `Colon` but before `Colon` it is consider.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew check out again space is consider before `Colon`.

Comment: If you add spaces at the last of a string then it will trim all the spaces[Not hard coded spaces] as you already mentioned in your result "RegNumber :". Before colon space doesn't removed because it is not at the last of the string. It's a basic logic of android, no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Because by default, android trim all the String to remove unnecessary spaces.. Say you accidentally pressed space bar and there were 20 spaces in your string file now,

```
<string name="regNumber">RegNumber :                           </string>
```

Android just trim the leading and trailing spaces. I never find any reason behind it. But I believe, it's useful to validate the string using Regex. [PS: I might be wrong]

See also: [Android's documentation on formatting string](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: Your answer is not work for me Read the `Question` carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) defined is constructed to ignore white spaces at the beginning, and at the end. It is defined in the first phase of compiler building process called [Lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

Comment: Your answer is not work for me Read the `Question` carefully.