# How to add leading white space (spaces) in TextView (Android)

Tags: android, string, textview, spaces

I am trying to add leading white space (spaces) to the string displayed in my TextView when I use setText(), but TextView just removes them from the String.

For example, say I want to display " 328".  I call textView.setText(" 328"), but what is displayed in the TextView is "328".  The TextView will always display:

```
328
```

Instead of:

```
 328
```

Please keep in mind that I must solve this while using .setText() and not through resources.  I have also tried prepending it with "\u00A0","\u0020", and "&#160" but they don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the spaces at the end and/or at the beginning of a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587056/how-to-keep-the-spaces-at-the-end-and-or-at-the-beginning-of-a-string)

Comment: .setText(" " + "328");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this below method to add space before text.

```
textView.setText("     "+"328");
```