# How to add padding/margin between two words in a string?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I would like to add a margin/padding between two words in a string.

I'm currently using SpannableString in order to customize the string. For font color and size etc. Now I need to add a fixed margin between the words. I tried adding \n\n in strings.xml but it is not accurate. 
What I did currently,

```
<string name="registration_success">You have been successfully registered 
                  and your number is: \n\n%1$s</string>
```

Any other ways?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587056/how-to-keep-the-spaces-at-the-end-and-or-at-the-beginning-of-a-string

Answer (score 0):

To use fixed margin or whitespace between two words of a string you can use:
&#160 for non-breakable whitespace and &#032 for regular space. As XML doesnt take whitespace as it is. It will trim that space.
By using &#160 or &#032 you can achieve regular padding or margin between words